# Read browser image and click without using selenium?

Tags: python, computer-vision

I was just trying to figure out how to get `python` to see the browser window and read the image there(I don't want to take a snapshot, if possible) process it and then click the relevant button on screen.

As a project I want to avoid selenium. I can't seem to find the correct `library` or any tutorials for this. Can someone tell me the library and possibly a tutorial?

I am on Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: Look into `opencv` and `pyautogui`

Comment: Thanks, I will start looking into them.